# 32.768 kHz crystal - oscilloscope signal interpretation

Tags: oscillator, oscilloscope, crystal, matching

As an exercise I measured (with a 100MHz 10x probe) the 32.768 kHz crystal signals on a board by varing the Cl1,/Cl2 capacitors.

Here are the results:

**12pF**

[image]

**15pF**

[image]

**22pF**

[image]

Can someone help me interpret these results? The frequency is roughly correct (I do not have an accurate way and instruments to measure it.)

In all the cases, the amplitude increases with 12pF. (I suppose it is a good thing, isn't it?)

Comment: [Crystal oscillators - my bare-bones website](http://www.stades.co.uk/XTAL%20Oscillator/XTAL%20Oscillator.html) and [Crystal loading](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/250608/crystal-oscillator-load-capacitance-again/250645#250645) and [crystal feedback resistor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/384602/feedback-resistor-value-for-a-crystal-oscillator/384613#384613) and [What frequency stability crystal do we need?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/600887/what-frequency-stability-crystal-do-we-need/600903#600903).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Crystal oscillator load capacitance, again](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/250608/crystal-oscillator-load-capacitance-again)

Comment: What exactly you need to get interpreted? More loading, less amplitude? The effect to frequency is so small that it can't be measured by scope, but more load will lower the frequency. You need just the right amount of load to get just the right frequency that is within your requirements.

Comment: well why don't use the scopes measurement facility to measure the frequency? seems to be good enough to measure 32.768 kHz...

Comment: As a hint, if you want to measure period on a scope, set the markers to span (for example) 10 periods and divide by 10, don't set them across half a period and multiply by 2. (Or just use the built in measurement feature of the scope)

Comment: It still won't be as accurate as using a frequency counter, but it will probably get you an extra signifcant figure.